# Subclassing NSManagedObject with swift 3 and Xcode 8 beta

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift3, xcode8

I've began to try use Core data with swift 3 and Xcode 8 beta. When I try to generate NSManagedObject subclasses from core data model and Create NSManagedObject subclass… option in Editor menu, Xcode 8 beta generates three files one of them is **_COREDATA_DATAMODELNAME_**+CoreDataModel.swift with the following content:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

___COREDATA_DATAMODEL_MANAGEDOBJECTCLASSES_IMPLEMENTATIONS___
```

In addition, the content of this file shows two warnings:

```
Expressions are not allowed at the top level.
Use of unresolved identifier '___COREDATA_DATAMODEL_MANAGEDOBJECTCLASSES_IMPLEMENTATIONS___'
```

Has anyones faced the same issue? Which is the meaning of this new file?

Thanks

Comment: I can't create a custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses in Xcode 8 beta. I have same problem.

Comment: I fixed that almost issue for objc by the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40788081/2246798

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's probably a (beta) clash with the new automatic subclass generation, which can be controlled in the entity inspector of the data model file.

From the [documentation (What's New In Core Data)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html)

> ## Xcode automatic subclass generation
>
> Xcode now supports automatic generation of `NSManagedObject` subclasses
>   in the modeling tool. In the entity inspector:
>
> - **Manual/None** is the default, and previous behavior; in this case you
>     should implement your own subclass or use `NSManagedObject`.
> - **Category/Extension** generates a class extension in a file named like
>     `ClassName+CoreDataGeneratedProperties`. You need to declare/implement
>     the main class (if in Obj-C, via a header the extension can import
>     named ClassName.h). -
> - **Class Definition** generates subclass files named
>     like `ClassName+CoreDataClass` as well as the files generated for
>     Category/Extension.
>
> The generated files are placed in DerivedData and
>   rebuilt on the first build after the model is saved. They are also
>   indexed by Xcode, so command-clicking on references and fast-opening
>   by filename works.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with these three options while wait for new releases of Xcode 8.

Comment: NOTE: You can also pick the language of the codeine in the file inspector, if like me you want to generate in Swift. For some reason mine was Objective C despite creating a Swift project… Then again it this is a beta to GM project migration.

Comment: what's the entity inspector? -found the answer: it's where you edit your entity, the .xcdatamodel file

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems with this developer beta Xcode 8. Some of them resolved Command + S (save changes) before I leave Data Model or before I generate NSManagedObject subclasses. I don't know why but in my case automatic save didn't work sometimes and some errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the problem with the .swift file cited above and found that commenting out the ___COREDATA... line got me by the error for now.  I'm not sure what it's supposed to accomplish.

I'm also finding that XCODE 8 has a tendency to forget about new fields that are added to CoreData entities and to repeatedly reset the CoreData model code generation target to Objective C, leading to a flurry of .h and .m files instead of swift files when it regenerates files.  Most of the issues that I've seen have been CoreData related, but have been workable so far.

Other than that, XCODE 8 has been surprisingly solid working with an app with 25 data entities and over 30 view controllers so I'm not complaining.