# Generating NSManagedObject Subclasses CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I just started a CoreData project. I created a CoreData model file and added some entities. These entities contain some attributes as well as some relationships. I then tried to generate the subclasses. I made to sure to select the right database and entities. When they generated, I got four files with a ton of errors.

The four files and errors are as follows:

1) TwitterUser+CoreDataClass.swift   //invalid redeclaration of 'TwitterUser'

2)Tweet+CoreDataClass.swift   //same as #1

3)TwitterUser+CoreDataProperties.swift   //'TwitterUser' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context, @NSManaged only allowed an instance property or method, Extensions may not contain stored properties

4) Tweet+CoreDataProperties.swift   //same as #3

Somebody please help. I can provide the code if needed.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351449/invalid-redeclaration-in-auto-code-generate-nsmanagedobject-subclass-swift-3 ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.