# Creating a new file using NSManagedObjectSubclass template in xcode 8

Tags: xcode, core-data

Looking to remake my core data files to include new properties. In Xcode 7 under CoreData there was the NSManagedObjectSubclass file type, I recently upgraded to Xcode 8 and now I don't see it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only options I see are to create a data model and mapping model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid redeclaration in auto code generate NSManagedObject Subclass Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351449/invalid-redeclaration-in-auto-code-generate-nsmanagedobject-subclass-swift-3)